# mysql: select records with maximum sub-values?

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I have a table with a primary:

```
PRIMARY KEY(`x`,`y`,`Version`,`Revision`)
```

On table like:

```
`x`,`y,`version`,`revision`,`data`
```

`x`, `y`, `version` and `revision` all count up from zero.

I am trying to figure out how to return the highest `revision` and its `data` for every `version`, given a specifiy `x` and `y`. And what indexes could I make to speed it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1
  JOIN (SELECT Version, MAX(Revision) Revision FROM table GROUP BY Version) t2
    ON t1.Version = t2.Version AND t1.Revision = t2.Revision
```

...to speed up the query you may add indexes on Version and Revision fields. Anyway - you should analyze it using `EXPAIN SELECT...` statement.

Comment: I assume you meant to have 'group by Version' for the inner statement.